# Java long calculations without freezes GUI (in single thread)

Tags: java

At the interview, me was asked question: "How to perform many calculations in single thread without freezes GUI component like Progress Bar or that would be able to check another user input? (Can execute only one thread)"

I answered that I can write async event loop.
But he told me that Java already have some mechanism for it. That java can use hardware parallelization of operation. What the classes or special words can used for this task?

Comment: Something like `javax.swing.SwingWorker` ? [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: No, SwingWorker run new thread.

Comment: Yep, I commented before you changed the title  to **single thread** ;)

Comment: `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` and basically call the same method, which calculates a small set of values and updates the progress bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, assuming we can't use either `SwingWorker` or Swing `Timer`, as they create a second thread to support their operations, the only choice you're left with is to use `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` to repeatedly call a method, which performs a small subset of the work and updates the UI before calling itself again (using `SwingUtilities#invokeLater`)

[image: Look ma, no threads]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class NoMoreThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NoMoreThreads();
    }

    public NoMoreThreads() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final int MAX = 1000;

        private JProgressBar pb;
        private JButton start;
        private int count;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            start = new JButton("Let's get this party started");
            start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    start.setEnabled(false);
                    calculate();
                }
            });

            pb = new JProgressBar(0, MAX);

            add(start, gbc);
            add(pb, gbc);
        }

        protected void calculate() {
            count++;
            if (count < MAX) {
                pb.setValue(count);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        calculate();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                start.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is clearly not what about the interviewer was saying.

Comment: Why? This does not freeze the UI and does not use any other threads? Since you don't seem to be able to solve it, how do you know this isn't a viable solution?

Comment: Based on the wording of your question, [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/fork-join-422606.html) seems to be what they are talking about, which is a clear contrition to the terms of their question, as this will still create a background thread

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I think too that they talking about `java.util.concurrent` and Fork/Join.

Comment: @IntFloat As I say though, using `java.util.concurrent` API still creates `Thread`s, just like `SwingWorker` and Swing `Timer`, so my question would be, how does that solve the problem with a single `Thread`?  If you consider that the EDT is a `Thread`?  These are questions that need to be better answered by the interviewers as the way you have stated the question contraindicates the "suggested" solution

Comment: Maybe they want to say one thread at the time. So `java.util.concurrent` can do that.

Comment: So can `SwingWorker` or Swing `Timer`, they only use a single thread each.  As I understand Fork/Join, it allows for a pool of threads which can be executed concurrently, but which, while one is waiting for a solution to be generated, can be re-used to start another task ... that's just my take on the blurb I read.  However, I think that will be closer to what they "seem" to be wanting